# Trademark symbol appears as capital T

Tags: c#

I have run into a peculiar issue while reading data from an xslx doc.
The data in the doc has the 'TM' symbol inside the circle.
When this is read it comes out as capital 'T'.
I am using EPPlus library to read the data like so:

```
var existingFile = new FileInfo(filePath);

                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
                {
                    ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
                    ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();

                    foreach (var item in currentWorksheet.Cells)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
                    }
                }
```

Any clues / suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Console does not support Unicode, and all output is automatically converted to default system locale for non-unicode apps (ASCII-based). There is no '™'symbol in ASCII, to the following code will print T:

```
Console.WriteLine("™");
```

but if you will save the same string to the file as Unicode, then ™ will be saved correctly:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("text.txt", "™");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("text.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a limitation of your display font face. The TM symbol you see is most likely unicode character 2122 => ™ or `&#0153` in html.

Some fonts don't display those higher codes well. Try using Arial rather than a monotype font and you may see the difference. The character map tool in windows really helps.

Another option is the item might be a symbol in a symbol font family. You can always use c# to find the unicode character of the char you have.