# Suggestions needed to Apply SuperScript to C# string For Xsl transformation

Tags: c#, xslt, superscript

I Want to apply SuperScript to String for display
It works fine with numbers in superscript, doesn't work for String characters.
Suggestions needed.

Works fine for : 
var o2 = "O₂";        // or "O\x2082"
var unit2 = "unit²";  // or "unit\xB2"

Does not work for :
var xyz = "ABC365\xBTM"

Can not get TM superscripted over string ABC365.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at these ones https://stackoverflow.com/a/3496389/920557 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156196/920557. Those answers explain what you are dealing with.

Comment: Not sure what any of this has to do with XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have completely misunderstood what is going on here, so I'll try a very basic explanation.

Unicode defines a large number of characters (some 1,114,111 if I remember right). These came from a large number of historic sources, and there's no great rhyme or reason about which characters made it in and which didn't. The available characters include some subscript and superscript digits, for example x2082 is subscript 2, and x00B2 is superscript 2. It also includes some special symbols such as the trademark symbol x2122 which are traditionally rendered with a superscript appearance.

But there's no general mechanism in Unicode to render any character in superscript or subscript rendition. If you want to write X<sub>*n*</sub>, Unicode won't help you: to achieve that I had to resort to mechanisms outside Unicode, specifically HTML tagging. HTML allows you to render anything as subscript or superscript; Unicode only handles a few select cases.

C# recognizes the escape sequences \xHH and \xHHHH (depending on context), where H is any hex digit, to represent special characters by their Unicode code point value. So if there's a codepoint x2082 meaning subscript 2, you can write it as \x2082 in a Unicode string literal. But there's no codepoint for subscript-lowercase-italic N, so there's no way of representing that.

Now when you write `\xBTM` it should be clear that's nonsense. `\x` must be followed by 2 or 4 hex digits (depending on context). If you want the trademark symbol, you can use \x2122. If you want the two characters "T" and "M" in superscript rendition, you're out of luck; if you need to pass that sort of thing around in your application, you will need to pass strings containing HTML markup, rather than just plain Unicode.

You indicate that you're trying to create strings that will be used as input to an XSLT transformation. My suggestion would to pass XML documents rather than plain strings: but I would need to understand the requirement in better detail before saying that's definitively the right solution.